# Problemas con una variable en PHP - MYSQL

Tags: php, base-de-datos, mysqli

Intentare plantear mis dudas lo mas claro posible,

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de inscripción de cursos/capacitaciones, en donde cada curso tiene una cantidad definida de vacantes, y en el formulario de inscripción, cuando el usuario ingresa sus datos, este va a un php que registra dichos datos en la base, pero también verifica si hay vacantes disponibles:

```
$conex=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","capacitaciones");
$result = mysqli_query($conex, "
    SELECT vacantes FROM cursos where vacantes >0 and id_curso=$id_curso
 ");
      if($result)
      {     
           while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {   
              $cant_vacantes = $registro['vacantes'];
              echo " - ", $cant_vacantes; 
         //     echo $cant_vacantes;  
          }
      }

if ($cant_vacantes==0){ 
  echo"<Script language='JavaScript' type='text/JavaScript'>
      alert('!Los cupos de este curso se han acabado!')
      window.location.href='#';
       </Script>";

 }else{ ...
```

Hasta acá todo bien, el problema esta que cuando la cantidad de vacantes en la base de datos es de cero, me muestra el siguiente aviso:

> Notice: Undefined variable: cant_vacantes in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP5.3.0\www\capacitacion\cursos\envia_mail_2019.php on line 97

Indica que la variable `cant_vacantes` no esta definida, entonces quisiera saber como validar esta variable en caso de que `cant_vacantes` me regrese un cero o un null,

De antemano, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Puesto que tu consulta requiere que vacantes>0 esto sólo pasa cuando no tienes resultados, y en ese caso no declaras $cant_vacantes y no existe, antes de hacer la consulta inicializa $cant_vacantes=0;

Comment: Gracias Carmen, quedo corregido te lo agradezco

Answer (score 1):

Desde luego, y como muy bien te indica Carmen, inicializar las variables siempre es recomendable, aunque en PHP sea opcional y escribas una línea extra de código.

Si quieres evitarlo, también puedes utilizar esta otra condición en el if, eliminando así el Notice. La función isset comprueba que la variable haya sido inicializada.

```
if (!isset($cant_vacantes)){ 
   ...
}
```

En cualquier caso, también puedes contar el número de registros que te devuelve la consulta, y así te aseguras de que en $can_vacantes siempre habrá un número, aunque sea un 0. Así te traes mucha menos información del servidor MySQL, lo que agilizará la ejecución de la aplicación que estás desarrollando.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) vacantes FROM cursos where vacantes >0 and id_curso=$id_curso
```

Si optas por esta solución, no pongas el !isset en el if.